# How do I the number im trying to check look through a range while in an if statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, range

I am new to the python language and I am writing code for a program that takes in a month as a string and a day as an int. I am up to the part where I need to check the date and I am unsure of how to go about it.

My current code for the part I am up to is this

```
for day in range(1,day):
    if month == 'January' and day == range(32):
        print('It is Winter')
```

The issue I am having is when it comes to the range(32) part. How do I make it so I can check the date number in a range from 1,31?

Comment: `day in range(1, 32)` will do it.  But you probably don't want to be doing this *inside* a `for day in range(1, day)` loop.

Comment: `if 1 <= day <= 31:`

Answer (score 1):

Use `day in range(...)` to check if `day` is in the given `range`.

Note that you probably don't want to do this in a loop.  I'd suggest putting the number of days in each month in a dict so you can just look it up, e.g.:

```
months = {
    'January': 31,
    'February': 29,
    'March': 31,
    # ...
}

month, day = input("Month?" ), int(input("Date? "))
if month not in months:
    print(f"{month} isn't a month")
elif day not in range(1, months[month] + 1):
    print(f"There aren't {day} days in {month}")
```

Comment: Ah Thank you! Im currently in a begginers class so we have not gotten to dicts yet. But this will be useful for the future. I thank you very much!